# Expressjs res.redirect() won't redirect

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I Realize there's a lot of topics like this,I've tried most of the solutions given there, but none of them seem to work.

I have a router that handles urls like "/pages"

```
module.exports = (app, mw) ->
  app.get '/pages/allow-ie7', routes.allow_ie7
  app.get '/pages/outdated-browser', routes.outdated_browser

  app.param ':page', (req, res, next, id) ->
    console.log ':page'
    Page.find id, (err, page) ->
    return next(err) if err?
    req.resource = page
    next()
```

routes.allow_ie7 looks like this:

```
exports.allow_ie7 = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log 'allow ie7 test'
  console.log req.session.canUseIE7

  req.session.canUseIE7 = true

  res.redirect 301, '/'
  return true
```

But while I can see the logging, it won't redirect me back to the homepage.
I'm not sure why this isn't working, am I forgetting to cancel the `next()`?

Answer (score 0):

use res.end(); after redirect:

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, while I can see the URL change, the actual page doesn't seem to refresh. Is there a way to perform a "hard" refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need the response code. Just pass the path '/' on 1st argument.

> res.redirect('/')
>   res.redirect '/'